# Defining new unit (year, century) in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I'm having a hard time figuring out the LaTeX commands to define new units of `year` and `century` in `siunitx`.

I'd like to write `\SI{3}{\cm\per\year}` and have it show: **3 cm yr-1**, or `\SI{42}{\micro\meter\per\century}` become **4.2E-5 m/century**

Comment: You can just write `\SI{3}{\cm\per yr}`, pehaps you could add a little more detail to your question?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In your preamble

```
\DeclareSIUnit\century{century}
\DeclareSIUnit\year{yr}
```

See the [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) manual (v2.1 series), Section 4.5, page 12.