# rpm in siunitx?

Tags: siunitx

I can't seem to find how to add `rpm` with the siunitx package. It would make sense to write something like `\SI{10}{\revolution\per\minute}` but of course this doesn't work, and the `\per\minute` part only gives me `min^-1`.

Comment: rpm is a frequency measure. As such, min^-1 is the correct (SI-compliant) unit.

Comment: For example http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6016: you need to declare a new unit

Comment: That made it. Could you write the answer so I can accept your answer?

Comment: I think we should rather close this question as duplicate of the question linked by Joseph instead of adding a new (same) answer here …

Comment: As long as people searching for `rpm` and `siunitx` finds this that would work.

Comment: @AlexG This is absolutely correct. If you have a look in [DIN 1301-1](https://www.beuth.de/en/standard/din-1301-1/133080569) it's not "allowed". ;)