# How to define a \degreeKelvin using siunitx?

Tags: siunitx

I know there is a command like `\degreeCelsius` in `siunitx`. But I do not know how to define something like `\degreeKelvin` (in a title like [this](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1029/JB083iB03p01257)). using `\qty{300}{\degree\Kelvin}` will add too many spaces.

Comment: There's no Degree Kelvin, there's only Kelvin. At least since 1967. That said, `\DeclareSIUnit{\degreeKelvin}{\ensuremath{{}^\circ}K}` could be a start.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I agree. But the paper I cited (1978) used `°K`.

Comment: If you want to print °K then write `°K` or define `\def\degreeKelvin{°K}` and write `\degreeKelvin`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general case of declaring a new unit is covered by [Defining new unit (year, century) in siunitx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6016/defining-new-unit-year-century-in-siunitx/6018). Here, the degree symbol is slightly tricky. Assuming you are not using `unicode-math` then a definition that matches that for `\degreeCelsius` would be

```latex
\DeclareSIUnit \degreekelvin
  {\ifmmode{}^{\circ}\else\textdegree\fi K}
```

(Other than Celsius, unit names are not capitalised.)

If you are loading `unicode-math`, then

```latex
\DeclareSIUnit\degreekelvin{°K}
```

should work.

However, for a 'one off' case like this, I'd be tempted just to use literal unit input

```latex
\qty{300}{{}^{\circ} K}
```

(or similar): you don't need all of the unit processing, you can be sure of math vs text mode, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I have `unicode-math` loaded, and it works for me! BTW, your answer has an extra three backticks.